# 10 small comma questions

Tags: commas

I am unsure about the use of commas in the following:

1. In this case study **(,)** only one method is investigated
2. To shift the load in time **(,)** heat pumps are needed.
3. Flexible loads **(,)** such as electric heating devices, refrigerators **(,)** and
   freezers will be important for future energy systems.
4. The components can coordinate the generation **(,)** consumption and
   storage of energy.
5. Algorithm A results in total costs of 20 € for that day **(,)** which is 5
   € lower compared to Algorithm B.
6. The electricity generation by renewable energy sources **(,)** like wind
   turbines and photovoltaic systems, **(,)** challenges the energy system.
7. The results show that Algorithm A **(,)** on average **(,)** leads to 10%
   improvement.
8. In the simulation of the previous and this chapter **(,)** every building
   uses a gas heating system.
9. While in the current system **(,)** the supply follows the demand **(,)** 
   in future **(,)** the demand has to follow the power supply.
10. Fossil fuels mainly generated the energy for buildings **(,)** whereas
     renewable energy accounted for only 18%.

I do not expect one of you to answer all of these questions. However,I'd appreciate every comment to each of those sentences. I'd be quite thankful if you could help me on that.

Update: Thanks for all the answers so far. Can anyone tell me his/her opinion on sentence 7.? Below one answer was given but I do not really understand it. It is correct to use commas in this sentence?

Update2: That about sentence 4.? Does there have to be a comma before the 'and'(like it is done in sentence 3.)

Comment: The second comma  in (3) is an example of [the Oxford comma](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/what-is-the-oxford-comma-and-why-do-people-care-so-much-about-it/).

Comment: I suggest you have a look at what the _Online Writing Lab_ at Purdue has to say about comma use. Here is their quick guide, and in the left side bar you will find links to further pages of advice on comma use: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/index.html

Comment: I like every comma except that those in 7 just get in the way, and 9 needs work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your comments. @YosefBaskin: So in 7 and 9 you would remove all commas?

Comment: In 7, the commas interfere with a short sentence. In 9, the first comma looks like a mistake, and I'd change the middle to read "the supply follows the demand, in *the* future the demand will..."

Comment: Thanks Yosef for your comment. What do you mean by "Interfere with a short sentence". Do you have a better option how I could not interfere with the short sentence. Shall I just not use the commas?

Comment: Would anyone mind commenting on sentence 7 (or on Yosef Baskin's comment). I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Americans say "in the future", but in the U.K. they often say "in future".

Comment: 3 is wrong because a comma is present at the start of a "parenthetical" but not at the end.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks for your comment. The second comma in (3) is an example of the Oxford comma (like  Kate Bunting  said in the beginning). So I guess it is not wrong

Comment: @YosefBaskin: I have to questions to you based on your answers. 1) What does 'interfere with a short sentence mean'? Would you use a comma or not (based on my sentence 7.) 2) Your suggestion for 9. is 'While, the supply follows the demand, in the future the demand will...' So is there no comma after 'future'?

Comment: "Interfere with a short sentence" on 7 means I would not add punctuation when a sentence is very short: "Dessert's ready and I'm happy." Comma rules ask for a comma, but really who needs one to understand? I say leave them out.

Comment: For 9, I'd prefer this: "While in the current system the supply follows the demand, in future the demand has to follow the power supply."

Comment: Thanks Yosef Baskin for your answer. Regarding 7: Would you use the commas if the sentence was longer? Regarding 9: So I should generally not use commas in sentence beginning with 'While'? I have seen a comma on many occasions if the sentence begin with 'While'

Comment: For sentences longer than 7, use commas there. For sentences starting with *while*, it all depends, but probable: While gardening, I wear gloves. While gardening is fun, it's a workout.